# When is this vs. when this is

Tags: word-order

Which one of the following is correct use? If both are correct, what difference does this change make in a conversation?

1. Do you know when *is this* being used?
2. Do you know when *this is* being used?

Comment: Personally, I would never say is before this. Replacing "this" with a noun makes your 1 example sound wrong with every word I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the sentence is already in a question for "Did you...?" so the clause "when this is..." does not need to be in question form as well; it is just awkwardly worded. The word "when" is a conjunction and forms - along with the rest of the sentence - a dependent clause. If used separately, "When is this...?" would be correct. Hope this is helpful!