# do you know who is the most... person is or who the most..person is

Tags: grammar

I know we say "do you know who he is / I don't know who he is" but I saw this sentence in an article translated by a Chinese famous translator who was born in 1921 so it is unlikely to send him an email to ask him such a question.

At the beginning of the translation is :

> Do you know who is the most well-known person in China?

so

> Do you know who is the most ... is in C

or

> Do you know who the most... is in C

Which one is correct? Both?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dou you know when is this / when this is?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351627/when-is-this-vs-when-this-is) // [Inversion – non-inversion in wh-questions with long phrases after the wh-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348010/inversion-non-inversion-in-wh-questions-with-long-phrases-after-the-wh-words) // [Inversion in affirmative sentences with a complex subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393475/inversion-in-affirmative-sentences-with-a-complex-subject)

Answer (score 0):

Both cannot be correct. Only the second sentence is correct.

"who is the most well-known person in China" is an interrogative Content/noun clause. When used as a dependent/subordinate clause under a main clause, it functions as a noun and takes those positions that a noun/pronoun can. However, as a dependent clause, it doesn't ask a direct question, but rather an indirect one.

Know is a transitive verb and hence takes an object(a noun/pronoun).

So, you say:

'Do you know who the most well-known person in China is?'

You see how the subject and the verb in that depended clause swapped their positions.

You could also say:

'Do you know who the most well-known person is in China? ', with the PP 'in China' at the end.

Comment: thank you for answering my question. i am sorry i made a typo there.. i was gonna ask "do you know who the .. is " or "do you know who is the ...". and i do know what you said above. what made me confused is the whole sentence "do you know who is the most ... in C", which was written by a famous translator, and i was puzzling if it's grammatically wrong. i love english but this sentence is beyong my understanding. i asked one of my friends who majored in English and she said,"do you know who he is" is correct, "do you know who IS the most... " is also correct.

Comment: and according to what you said, there is only one correct way to say this, that is "do you know who S + V", am i right? thank you !

Comment: 'do you know + V + S' could be possible if the subject of the dependent clause is very long. That is, it's modified by long phrases or clauses. In that event, the construction 'do you know + S + V' sounds a little awkward. You can refer to these links for more information:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348010/inversion-non-inversion-in-wh-questions-with-long-phrases-after-the-wh-words

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351627/when-is-this-vs-when-this-is          https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393475/inversion-in-affirmative-sentences-with-a-complex-subject

Comment: thank you for providing me these questions but i still have a little bit problem here, and i think you have some point here that you said it's based on if the S's modified by long phrases or clauses. and let's go back to the question i asked, "do you know who is the most well-known person in C" or " do you know who the most well-known person is in C", which one is 100% correct, that's all i want to know. thank you !